# Xpath not execute properly

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have following Xpath

```
"//*[@id="idDownloadDataMenuo:portalgo~r:report"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/img"
```

and following CSS

```
"#idDownloadDataMenuo\3a portalgo\7e r\3a report > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.shadowMenuCell > a:nth-child(1)"
```

While i am trying to click on that path post find throwing below error .

tried lot of combination as well
**"Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='idDownloadDataMenuo:portalgo~r:report']//td[text()='CSV Format']"}"**

the same Xpath is working in console as well below is the output.

```
''' $x("//*[@id='idDownloadDataMenuo:portalgo~r:report']//td[text()='CSV Format']")
 '''
```

below is my code

```
browser.execute_script('''window.open("https://XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX=YYYYYYYYYYYY%20report","_blank");''')
time.sleep(40)

#findpath = "//td[text()='CSV Format'] or //td[contains(text(),'report')]"
findpath = "//*[@id='idDownloadDataMenuo:portalgo~r:report']//td[text()='CSV Format']"

browser.find_element_by_xpath(findpath).click()
```

My Complete HTML tag For CSV part only similarly PDF ,EXCEL are also present with same class .

```
<tr><td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="shadowMenuCell"><a class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin" name="SectionElements" href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="NQWClearActiveMenu();return Download('saw.dll?Go&amp;ViewID=o%3aportalgo%7er%3areport&amp;Action=Download&amp;SearchID=fk3n3gl49dtd24splb64lli3lm&amp;Style=blafp&amp;ViewState=ok0jv8tnkb2ckftn5ucih1hnnq&amp;ItemName=Anil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&path=%2fusers%2fj000432%2fAnil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&Format=csv&Extension=.csv');"><table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="MenuItemIconCell"><img alt="" src="res/sk_blafp/catalog/exporttocsv_ena.png"></td><td class="MenuItemTextCell">CSV Format</td></tr></table></a><a class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin" name="SectionElements" href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="NQWClearActiveMenu();return Download('saw.dll?Go&amp;ViewID=o%3aportalgo%7er%3areport&amp;Action=Download&amp;SearchID=fk3n3gl49dtd24splb64lli3lm&amp;Style=blafp&amp;ViewState=ok0jv8tnkb2ckftn5ucih1hnnq&amp;ItemName=Anil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&path=%2fusers%2fj000432%2fAnil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&Format=txt&Extension=.csv');"><table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="MenuItemIconCell"><img alt="" src="res/sk_blafp/catalog/exporttocsv_ena.png"></td><td class="MenuItemTextCell">Tab delimited Format</td></tr></table></a><a class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin" name="SectionElements" href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="NQWClearActiveMenu();return Download('saw.dll?Go&amp;ViewID=o%3aportalgo%7er%3areport&amp;Action=Download&amp;SearchID=fk3n3gl49dtd24splb64lli3lm&amp;Style=blafp&amp;ViewState=ok0jv8tnkb2ckftn5ucih1hnnq&amp;ItemName=Anil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&path=%2fusers%2fj000432%2fAnil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&Format=xml&Extension=.txt');"><table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="MenuItemIconCell"><img alt="" src="res/sk_blafp/catalog/exporttoxml_ena.png"></td><td class="MenuItemTextCell">XML Format</td></tr></table></a>
```

FOR...MHT

```
<tr><td class="shadowRight">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class="shadowOffsetCellBottom"></td><td class="shadowBottom">&nbsp;</td><td class="shadowCorner"></td></tr>      </table></div><a class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin" name="SectionElements" href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="NQWClearActiveMenu();Download('saw.dll?Go&amp;ViewID=o%3aportalgo%7er%3areport&amp;Action=Download&amp;SearchID=fk3n3gl49dtd24splb64lli3lm&amp;Style=blafp&amp;ViewState=ok0jv8tnkb2ckftn5ucih1hnnq&amp;ItemName=Anil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&path=%2fusers%2fj000432%2fAnil%20-%20Steering%20vs%20Costs%20tracker%20report&Format=mht'); return false"><table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="MenuItemIconCell"><img alt="" src="res/sk_blafp/catalog/exporttomhtml_ena.png"></td><td class="MenuItemTextCell">Web Archive (.mht)</td></tr></table></a><a class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin" href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="return false;" onmouseover="saw.menuItemMouseOver(event,'idDownloadDataMenuo:portalgo~r:report');"><table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="MenuItemIconCell"><img alt="" src="res/sk_blafp/catalog/exporttocsv_ena.png"></td><td class="MenuItemTextCell">Data</td><td class="MenuItemRightArrowCell"><img src="res/sk_blafp/common/menurtarrow.gif" title="Download columnar data" alt="Download columnar data"></td></tr></table></a></td>
```

thanks in advance ...

Comment: Below is the HTML code for the same. ''' <table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="MenuItemIconCell"><img alt="" src="res/sk_blafp/catalog/exporttocsv_ena.png"></td><td class="MenuItemTextCell">CSV Format</td></tr></table>'''

Comment: There are no elements with ID `idDownloadDataMenuo:portalgo~r:report` in your HTML.